# Blazor NavigationManager.NavigateTo changes URL but does not load page

Tags: navigation, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I try to change the page from navigation menu.
I click on a button in the navigation menu.
An OnClick event handler gets called.
It executes `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/target")`.
In the browser the url changes to http://baseaddress/target as expected. But the target page does not show up. The content of the current page stays.
That is not the expected behaviour, is it?
I am aware of the second parameter named forceLoad. But I do not want to fully reload the page from server. I wish the navigation to happen on client side.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What ``@page`` directive has the component that should be available at ``/target``. What ``@page`` directive has the current component? One reason why this navigation "fails" could be that both links point to the same - the current component.

Comment: The target page directive is ```@page "/target"```. The current one is ```@page "/"``` They do not have the same. Also, when I directly enter http://baseaddress/target in browser it goes where it should. But that is like forceLoad = true

Comment: It seems unusual that it is not working. I can't pinpoint it yet; I can suggest further diagnostics. Do you have any output in the Output window or console in the browser? In your ``/target`` component, can you verify that a lifecycle hook, like ``OnInitilized``, is called? The NavigationManager has an event ``LocationChanged`` is that event fired? Is there a third-party js library interfering with the HTML5 history API?

Comment: Indeed. No there is no extra output generated from using NavigationManager at all. ```OnInitialized``` does not get called on ```/target``` component. But the ```LocationChanged``` event gets fired. ```IsNavigationIntercepted``` is false and ```Location``` contains the correct URL. I do not use any third-party js. The only third party library I use is bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

For me `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(REDIRECT_PATH,` **forceLoad: true**`)` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

First, set up a component with a `@page` directive.

Second, use the `<NavLink>` to navigate instead of handle `onclick` yourself.

For more information, see Blazor School [Routing and Navigation](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-server/routing-and-navigation-574891).

Comment: Wie ```<NavLink>``` component the same problem persists. URL in browser gets set correctly, but the page does not get loaded

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and it was my own mistake. I put the `@Body` tag in MainLayout.razor not directly into its own html, but rater into the another razor components child content

```
<div id="rootContainer">
    <ContainerComponent>
        <Content>
            <MainMenu />
            <div id="rootContentContainer">
                   @Body
            </div>
        </Content>
    </MessageBoxContainer>
</div>
```